# Entity Code first with shared host production DB

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

So I have a MVC4 project working on localhost and it is time to upload it to a shared environment.

Being that I am using a shared hosting environment I can not use the built in Initializers. So I created a backup of my mdf file (.bak) and uploaded it to my production environment. Everything looked right... The tables were all there.. but when I run my application I get this exception :

The model backing the 'YourContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

---

Got it working !

I added a custom initializer.

```
public class ProductionInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<AvariceContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(AvariceContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

The solution... is hackish, but works. If anyone could shed some light, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I found the MigrationHistory system's table. The two Dbs match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have not updated the EF model since creating the database you can just delete the _MigrationHistory table. 
This is just used to ensure the db and model are in sync but it does not work in the scenario you outllined.

In future, you can still use the Migrations feature of EF by adding '-script' to the flag to the update-database command you execute in the development environment as below. This will generate a migration script which you can execute on the production database.

```
> update-database -script
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Got it working ! I added a custom initializer."

Why this works:...
You can access the database despite the fact that EF sees some subtle difference.
Your code implements  IDatabaseInitializer and ignores the chance (empty method) to initalize or MIGRATE to latest version. So Ef thinks the DB isnt right, and you continue anyway.

Not a long term view to steady state EF access.
I would look at getting a Migrate to latest version working.

> Being that I am using a shared hosting environment I can not use the built in Initializers."

Why not ?